# For an expression need to remove space between the operators alone

Tags: python-3.x, string, whitespace

I have an expression and i need to remove space between the operators.
For example
rule_expr = ( 'name' in ( "abc","bcd" )) and ( 'age' <  = 60 ).
Here I need to remove space between '<='. The expression varies each time. I need a general statement to remove space between any 2 operators (<>=!).

I m using shlex.shlex() for moulding an expression but it puts space between the operators and the expression is failing. I need to remove the space between them.

Answer (score 1):

## Answer 1

```py
def remove_operator_spaces(expression):
    expression = expression.replace("   ", ' ').replace("  ", ' ')
    for i in ("< =", "> =", "< >", "> =", "= =", "! ="):
        expression = expression.replace(i, i.replace(' ', '')) # eg. replace("< =", "<=")
    
    return expression


expression = """\
( 'name' in ( "abc","bcd" )) and ( 'age' <   = 60 and 'age' > = 13)"""

res = remove_operator_spaces(expression)
print(res)
```

Output:

```
( 'name' in ( "abc","bcd" )) and ( 'age' <= 60 and 'age' >= 13)
```

Just using hardcoded logics and replacements of spaces. The code is pretty much self explanatory. If not, let me know in the comments.

## Answer 2

```py
def remove_operator_spaces(exp):
    exp = exp.replace("   ", ' ').replace("  ", ' ')
    for i in ("< =", "> =", "< >", "> =", "= =", "! ="):
        exp = exp.replace(i, i.replace(' ', '')) # eg. replace("< =", "<=")
    
    # adding a space intentionally if the operation is inside a double quote
    # eg. "abc" <= "bcd" -> "abc" < = "bcd"
    operators = ('<', '>', '=', '!')
    isQuote = False
    for i, char in enumerate(exp):
        if char == '"':
            isQuote = not isQuote

        # only matches for <=, >=, ==, !=
        # `exp[i+1] in operators`` could be replaced by exp[i+1] != ' ' as well
        if isQuote and char in operators and exp[i+1] in operators:
            exp = exp[:i+1] + ' ' + exp[i+1:]
            isQuote = False
    return exp

expression = """\
( 'name' in ( "abc","bcd" )) and ( 'age' < = 60 and 'age' > = 13) and ('percent' in ("maths >    = 123")"""
res = remove_operator_spaces(expression)
print(res)
```

This one removes the spacings only if the expression is inside double quotes **"**

Output:

```
( 'name' in ( "abc","bcd" )) and ( 'age' <= 60 and 'age' >= 13) and ('percent' in ("maths > = 123")
```

## Answer 3 ( regex ):

```py
import re

def remove_operator_spaces(expression):
    operators = ['<', '>', '=', '!']
    pattern = r'\s*([{}])\s*'.format(''.join(re.escape(op) for op in operators))
    return re.sub(pattern, '\\1', expression)

expression = """\
( 'name' in ( "abc","bcd" )) and ( 'age' <   = 60 and 'age' > = 13)"""

res = remove_operator_spaces(expression)
print(res)
```

Output:
`( 'name' in ( "abc","bcd" )) and ( 'age'<=60 and 'age'>=13)`

Let's explain the `remove_operator_spaces` function:

- `\s*` : This matches zero or more whitespace characters.
- `([{}])` : This is a capturing group that matches one character. The `{}` is a placeholder that will be replaced by the joined operators. It captures any one of the specified operators eg. `<`, `=`.
- `''.join(re.escape(op) for op in operators)` : This part generates a string by iterating over each operator in the `operators` list and escaping any special characters. Here's how it works:

  - `re.escape(op) for op in operators` is a generator expression that iterates over each operator in the operators list and applies the `re.escape` function to escape any special characters present in the operator. The `re.escape` function ensures that the operators are treated as literal characters in the regular expression.
- `''.join(...)` : This joins the escaped operators into a single string with no separator. For example, if the operators list is `['<', '>', '=', '!']`, the result will be `'<>=!'`.
- `'\\1'` : This is the replacement string. The `\\1` refers to the first captured group in the pattern. In our case, the captured group is the operator without surrounding spaces. By using `\\1` as the replacement, we are effectively replacing the matched pattern with just the captured operator.

Comment: I don't want to remove space if only one of the operator is present, I want to remove between the operators

Comment: Eg: a > 2 and a < = 10 then output should be : a > 2 and a <= 10

Comment: @Therealhunterz I edited the answer with another simple one. It'll output as you wanted

Comment: This works...thank you so much.... Is it possible to remove space only if they are not inside double quotes. ( 'name' in ( "abc","bcd" )) and ( 'age' < = 60 and 'age' > = 13) and ('percent' in ("maths > = 123"). Then output should be: ( 'name' in ( "abc","bcd" )) and ( 'age' <= 60 and 'age' >= 13) and ('percent' in ("maths > = 123")

Comment: @Therealhunterz I've added another answer ( answer 2 ). 
Please mark this as answer if this fulfils your need.